# Softmax cross entropy loss for single batch in python

Tags: python, neural-network, loss-function, softmax, cross-entropy

i want to ask how to implement cross entropy loss for single batch in neural network, where the equation is:
[image]

this is my code for cross entropy only for single example:

```
def softmax_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    softmax_cross_entropy_loss_single = - np.sum([y * np.log(x) for x, y in zip(y_pred, y_true)])
    softmax_cross_entropy_grad = y_pred - y_true
    return softmax_cross_entropy_loss, softmax_cross_entropy_grad
```

how to implement this for one batch (using the equation above)?

Comment: Generally, we take mean or sum of the losses across a batch.